# PostgreSQL Xpath to select element and it's child attribute as two columns

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

I have a table **history (id int, content xml)** in postgreSQL. XML content for one of the id as as following

```
<history-data>
      <history recorded-date="20110601">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
             <last-name>CIENA LUXEMBOURG</last-name>
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20110517">
              <last-name>NORTEL NETWORKS LIMITED</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
      <history recorded-date="20110601">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
              <last-name>CIENA CORPORATION</last-name>
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20110527">
              <last-name>CIENA LUXEMBOURG</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
      <history recorded-date="20090430">
        <assignees>
          <assignee>
             <last-name>NORTEL NETWORKS</last-name> 
          </assignee>
        </assignees>
        <assignors>
          <assignor execution-date="20090424">
              <last-name>MAK, GARY</last-name>
          </assignor>
          <assignor execution-date="20090424">
              <last-name>VELEZ, EDGAR</last-name>
          </assignor>
        </assignors>
      </history>
    </history-data>
```

Here, i want to get last-name & it's respective execution-date. For the above example, i want the following output

```
last-name                   execution-date
================            ==============
CIENA LUXEMBOURG              20110517
CIENA CORPORATION             20110527
NORTEL NETWORKS               20090424
```

I am able to generate all possible combinations using the following SQL query but not able to get output like above

```
SELECT id, unnest(CAST(xpath('/history-data/history/assignees/assignee/last-name/text()',content) AS text)::text[]) AS last-name,
unnest(CAST(xpath('/history-data/history/assignors/assignor/@execution-date',content) AS text)::text[]) AS execution-date
FROM history
WHERE id = 10
```

any suggestions on how can this be done ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to iterate over all `history` nodes and get appropriate elements with [`xpath()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-xml.html) function. By default, result of xpath extraction returns *array* of *xml*, that's why we need to get actual value with array index `(...)[1]`; sample query may be the following:

```
SELECT
  (xpath('//assignee/last-name/text()',xml_element))[1] AS "last-name",
  (xpath('//assignor/@execution-date',xml_element))[1] AS "execution-date"
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(xpath('//history',content)) AS xml_element FROM history
  WHERE id = 10
) t;
```

Result is:

```
     last-name     | execution-date 
-------------------+----------------
 CIENA LUXEMBOURG  | 20110517
 CIENA CORPORATION | 20110527
 NORTEL NETWORKS   | 20090424
(3 rows)
```

### EDITION

When `assignees` has multiple `assagnee` nodes query should use `unnest()` to get all array elements:

```
SELECT
  unnest(xpath('//assignee/last-name/text()',xml_element)) AS "last-name",
  unnest(xpath('//assignor/@execution-date',xml_element)) AS "execution-date"
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(xpath('//history',content)) AS xml_element FROM history
  WHERE id = 10
) t;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine but it is not giving correct results when i have multiple assignees & one assignor in single history. In this case i want to get both assignees with same execution-date. Any idea on how can this be done ?

Comment: just use `unnest()` when you do have multiple entries of `assignee` @GainiRajeshwar

Answer (score 2):

What your request does is find all the assignees, and, independently, find all the execution dates, and returns the cartesian product, which is probably not what you actually want.

What you want is:

- find all `history` elements
- then for each `history` element, find the text/attribute you're interested in.

This means using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    unnest(xpath('./assignees/assignee/last-name/text()',item))::text,
    unnest(xpath('./assignors/assignor/@execution-date',item))::text
FROM (
    SELECT
        unnest(xpath('/history-data/history',content)) AS item
    FROM history
    WHERE id = 10
    ) s
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Note that you will probably get weird results if you have several `assignee`s in a single `history` element. Also, not sure if you want all `execution-date`s, or just the first, or last, or...

**EDIT**

To get all `assignee`s, but only the first `execution-date` listed:

```
SELECT
    unnest(xpath('./assignees/assignee/last-name/text()',item))::text,
    (xpath('./assignors/assignor/@execution-date',item))[1]::text
FROM (
    SELECT
        unnest(xpath('/history-data/history',content)) AS item
    FROM history
    WHERE id = 10
    ) s
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this works fine when there is single assignee. I want this to work even when there are several assignees in a single history element. In this case i want all assignees with first execution-date (in case if there are multiple assignors & execution-dates in single history)

Comment: First date listed, or first date in chronological order (if there's a difference)?

Comment: @jacron first date listed

Comment: @jacron Thank you for that. But group by won't work on xml element here. You have to cast it into text or any other datatype. updated the answer accordingly.